# Spring data make query to override all object fields

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data

I'm using Spring data and I have to change all fields of one object.
Usually I use for example:

```
@Modifying  
@Query("UPDATE Car u SET u.datatable= ?2 WHERE u.idCar = ?1")
void setDatatable(int idCar, String datatable);
```

in my repository class. Now I should use

```
@Modifying  
@Query("UPDATE OilSample u SET all fields WHERE u.idOilSample = oilSampleMap.idOilSample")
void modify(OilSampleMap oilSampleMap);
```

but idOilSample and all my fields are in OilSampleMap instance (it has all the OilSample fields). Is it possible to use `@Query` annotation or Query Methods? Thanks

Comment: Pass the `OilSampleMap` instance to the `save` method of repository

Comment: they are two different classes OilSampleMap and OilSample , after mapping to OilSample it works